# Como fazer uma chamada de canal de método em uma instância vm-entry-point?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hoje estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação flutter que tem alguns códigos nativos, ou seja faço uso do channel para recuperar alguns recursos nativos, até então minha aplicação funciona bem, porém ao usar a libs para ter uma janela flutuante em qualquer parte do sistema eu preciso usar o vm-entry-point para instanciar essas janelas.

Exemplo:

```
@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")
void overlayMain() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MessangerChatHead(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Ao fazer isso consigo fazer uma janela flutante no app, porém dentro da classe dart messagerchatheader, ela não consegue achar meu channel da aplicação, sendo que em outras partes do app sem ser um vm-entry-point consigo chamar normalmente funções que esta na parte nativa, alguém ja teve esse problema?

Pelo pouco que pesquisei vi que o vm-entry-point é usado para ser chamado do lado do nativo, ou seja o kotlin chama o flutter, e talvez por isso ele não encontra o channel flutter que uso no resto de minha aplicação.

a função que uso para chamar a parte nativa é essa

```
 static Future<double> getCpuLoadPerCore(int core) async {
     try {
       double result = await platform.invokeMethod("cpuLoadPerCore", {"coreNumber": core});

       return double.parse(result.toStringAsFixed(2));
     } on PlatformException catch (e) {
       return Future.value(0);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho que o problema pode ser que o `vm-entry-point` é um ponto de entrada para o aplicativo Flutter que é executado no processo separado do resto do aplicativo. Isso significa que você precisa garantir que o canal Flutter está disponível para o processo da janela flutuante também.

Uma solução é inicializar o canal Flutter dentro da função `overlayMain` antes de chamar o `runApp`. Algo assim:

```
@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")
void overlayMain() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  const MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel("your_channel_name");
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MessangerChatHead(),
    ),
  );
}
```

E então na classe `MessengerChatHead` você pode acessar o canal Flutter através da variável `methodChannel`.

Isso deve resolver o problema e você deve ser capaz de usar o canal Flutter na sua janela flutuante normalmente.

Comment: Então, eu tentei fazer dessa forma chamando o vm-prefer inline mas mesmo assim ele não acha o channel da aplicação, eu estava usando essa biblioteca, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window, tentei até incorporar ela diretamente no app nativamente sem ser um plugin para ter acesso ao channel do app vamos supor, hoje eu tenho o channel kotlinNative esse eu consigo invocar em qualquer local do app, porém na janela ele diz que uma função que já chamo em outras telas e ja uso, diz que a função não esta implementada no lado nativo.

Comment: Testei da forma acima, mas ainda continua sem funcionar.